# Automatically alter button background and text appearance when pressed (like iOS)?

Tags: android, shadow, android-button, states, pressed

In iOS, if I set a button's background to an image, when I press the button, the whole content of the button (including the text) will be shadowed. Can I achieve the same effect in Android, or do I have to use different images for different states? Also, even if I use different images for different states, how do I make the text also shadowed? A dirty way is to set a `OnClickListener` to the button and programatically shadow the text when pressed, but are there any other ways?

Comment: Is it a toggle button, where the state can be up or down, or a regular button where it only appears different as it's being clicked on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I´ve been trying to find a solution for this for a while now but couldn´t find anything so I came up with a pretty neat solution which works on all image buttons. Just like iOS.

- Create a Black, 10% transparent image and save it as PNG. I call it button_pressed.png. You can use this image, http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/7924/buttonpressed.png
- Create a drawable called something relevant, I call it "button_pressed_layout.xml"

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"  />
  </selector>
  ```
- Now put your button image in the LinearLayout and then the Button inside the LinearLayout. In the Button use button_pressed_layout.xml as background.

  ```
      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/button_image">
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/myButtonId"
              android:text="@string/Continue"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_layout"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              android:textSize="16dp" >                   
          </Button>
      </LinearLayout>
  ```

That´s it!

Answer (score 3):

To get a pressed-state without creating a 2nd button image, I created an OnTouchListener to change the button's alpha.  This is not the most beautiful pressed state, but gives an effective automatic behavior.

```
public class PressedStateOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    PressedStateOnTouchListener( float alphaNormal )
    {
        mAlphaNormal    = alphaNormal;
    }

    public boolean onTouch( View theView, MotionEvent motionEvent )
    {
        switch( motionEvent.getAction() ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                theView.setAlpha( mAlphaNormal / 2.0f );
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                theView.setAlpha( mAlphaNormal );
                break;
        }

        // return false because I still want this to bubble off into an onClick
        return false;
    }

    private float   mAlphaNormal;
}
```

In your Activity, apply this listener to each button:

```
Button theButton =  (Button)findViewById( R.id.my_button_id );
theButton.setOnTouchListener( new PressedStateOnTouchListener( theButton.getAlpha() ));
```

Comment: This gives the "opposite" of a pressed state. You should darken the image to show pressed, not lighten it. and on a white background this lightens it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give the button itself different effects, I believe you need to use custom images, as seen [here](http://bend-ing.blogspot.com/2008/10/android-how-to-implement-custom-button.html) and, in less detail [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/03/custom-buttons-on-android.html) As for the text, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928971/does-setshadowlayer-work-on-a-button) looks like it would do the trick for the shadow